# Songs Under the Chuppah

Tags: minhag, song-poetry, wedding, provenance

The is a widespread wedding custom to sing a short benediction, מי אדיר‎, when the groom arrives under the canopy, and to sing מי בן שיח‎, for the bride as she arrives and walks around the groom.

The Kitzur Shulkhan Arukh [mentions](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur147) singing according to the custom of the place, and I understand why it would be fitting to sing such things in particular at the ceremony, but where do these passages come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Nitei Gavriel Nisuin 1 17:7:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=126&hilite=) the source of מי אדיר is Sefer Birchas Hamazon Dierenfort 452, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 147:65

Per [Yismach Lev page 82](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9766&st=&pgnum=116&hilite=) the source of מיבן שיח is Machzor Vitri 325.

Comment: Does anyone have information regarding "Sefer Birchas Hamazon Dierenfort"?